# Opening a custom url link in Safari/GMail

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, email, url-scheme

I am sending a custom url scheme link inside an email:

```
[body appendString:@"<div><a href=\"my-custom-url-scheme:test\"><button type=\"button\">Open in App</button></a></div>"];
```

This successfully adds a button in the email I am sending which, when tapped, opens my app (if it is installed).

This works fine when I open the email in mail.app on the iOS device, but doesn't do anything when I open the mail in Gmail (both via Safari and the native GMail app).

Is this a limitation of the framework? Or should safari be able to recognize these links?

Comment: I think it must be something GMail is doing - I uploaded the same line of html to a web server and it opened fine from safari.

Comment: I've run into the same problem.  I'm also assuming it's what you think - gmail is ignoring these custom schemes.

Comment: Confirmed, as of April 25, 2013 Gmail still ignores iOS custom url scheme urls.

Comment: And still, as of April 1, 2015 @pchap10k

Comment: Still it ignores as of May 18 2016

Comment: Still the same, February 2018

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best solution I've found for this is to link to a PHP script on a web server that takes parameters and redirects the request to your custom URL scheme within Safari.

This link will be in the email:

http://myserver.com/_script.php?parameter=one

This then redirects to:

myappscheme://open/?parameter=one

It does mean you have to open Safari to process the link, but given that you're opening the link from the GMail app anyway, I think thats a minor issue to get this working correctly.

Comment: I'm actually finding that this doesn't work for me via Gmail in iOS Safari.  My expressjs app is issuing a redirect to my custom URL scheme but Safari seems to just ignore it (I get a blank screen).  Seems like it *should* work, but I just can't get it going...

Comment: What if there is no internet connection when user tries to open the link from gmail client?

Comment: They'll immediately see a 'Cannot Connect' type error in Safari and the process will not go any further. Having an internet connection when this happens is the only way my method will work.